# Activerecord default_scope is bleeding between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 classes that use the same database:

```
class Enum < AR:Base
  self.table_name = 'enums'
end

class Language < AR:Base
  self.table_name = 'enums'
  default_scope where(category: Category.find_by_name('language'))
end

class Region < AR:Base
  self.table_name = 'enums'
  default_scope where(category: Category.find_by_name('region'))
end
```

I'm using the default_scope to keep the 3 of the separate at the class level.  This mostly works fine.

Case 1

```
en = Language.create(label: 'English')
en.category.name == 'language' #true
```

Case 2

```
united_states = Region.create(label: 'US')
united_states.category.name == 'region' #false !!!
```

Case 1 and 2 work fine when I test them in isolation, but when I run them back-to-back, some wires get crossed, and the united_states category becomes "language".  Some how the 2 classes are interacting with each other.  What's causing this?  Is  this a bug in activerecord, or am I doing something wrong here?

Note: I'm using activerecord 4.2

Comment: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/

Comment: Also, why not use STI? (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

Comment: @BradWerth I've read that using default_scope is discouraged, but I think this is one of the few cases where it should be useful because I actually always want the scope to apply in every case.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom I don't think STI would work well in my use case because STI requires using a type column to tell AR what database records map to which class,  instead of this column, my data uses a separate category table that says what each record is.  Also my data has many categories, ~10, that  are interacted with via the Enum class, but only 2 special categories, Region and Language, that are interacted with via their own specialized classes.  I could still add a type column to this situation, but then I'd be partially duplicating the category data.